# Configuring Cartographer for Robustness Against the Kidnapped Robot Problem

Tags: ros2, slam, robot-localization, lidar, cartographer

I'm currently working on a project using the Cartographer SLAM system and have encountered a significant challenge related to the "kidnapped robot problem."

For those unfamiliar, this problem arises when a robot is moved to an unknown location without its knowledge, and it must then reorient itself and determine its new position in the environment. In my case, after the robot is moved, it struggles to accurately re-localize itself within the pre-existing map.

I am reaching out to this knowledgeable community for advice or suggestions on how to tweak my Cartographer configuration to make it more robust against such scenarios.

I'm using a lidar. The environment is indoor, static environment, it has furnitures which provide environmental features.

Here is my current cartographer.lua settings

```
include "map_builder.lua"
include "trajectory_builder.lua"

options = {
  map_builder = MAP_BUILDER,
  trajectory_builder = TRAJECTORY_BUILDER,
  map_frame = "map",
  tracking_frame = "base_link",
  published_frame = "odom",
  odom_frame = "odom",
  provide_odom_frame = false,
  publish_frame_projected_to_2d = false,
  use_odometry = false,
  use_nav_sat = false,
  use_landmarks = false,
  num_laser_scans = 1,
  num_multi_echo_laser_scans = 0,
  num_subdivisions_per_laser_scan = 1,
  num_point_clouds = 0,
  lookup_transform_timeout_sec = 0.2,
  submap_publish_period_sec = 0.3,
  pose_publish_period_sec = 5e-3,
  trajectory_publish_period_sec = 30e-3,
  rangefinder_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  odometry_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  fixed_frame_pose_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  imu_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  landmarks_sampling_ratio = 1.,
}

MAP_BUILDER.use_trajectory_builder_2d = true

TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.min_range = 0.12
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.max_range = 3.5
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.missing_data_ray_length = 3.
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.use_imu_data = false
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.use_online_correlative_scan_matching = true 
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.motion_filter.max_angle_radians = math.rad(0.1)


TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.ceres_scan_matcher.occupied_space_weight = 100
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.ceres_scan_matcher.translation_weight = 100
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.ceres_scan_matcher.rotation_weight = 10

-- TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_nD.real_time_correlative_scan_matcher.linear_search_window
-- TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_nD.real_time_correlative_scan_matcher.angular_search_window 
-- TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.real_time_correlative_scan_matcher.translation_delta_cost_weight = 0.01
-- TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.real_time_correlative_scan_matcher.rotation_delta_cost_weight = 0.01


POSE_GRAPH.constraint_builder.min_score = 0.9
POSE_GRAPH.constraint_builder.global_localization_min_score = 0.9
POSE_GRAPH.optimize_every_n_nodes = 10 

return options
```

The primary issue is that after the robot is "kidnapped" and placed in a new location, it fails to recognize its new position and instead continues to extend the existing map inaccurately. I am looking for ways to enhance the system's ability to re-localize in the existing map after such disruptions.

I've tried tweaking Ceres scan matcher settings and real time correlative scan matcher settings, but still have problems.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, experiences, or suggestions you could share. If anyone has tackled similar issues or knows of resources that could be helpful, please let me know.